# Copy and paste cells based on font color and paste value based on relative positioning

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I have a set of cells that are always going to have green font (located in Current_Scenerio range). I want to copy and paste the values into a new range (Thesis_A).

With the current code it's able to select copy the value based on when the cell is formatted green. But I'm having trouble pasting these into a new range with relative positioning.

I need to keep the ranges dynamic so I can't use offset with absolute positioning, it all has to be relative as the range will be changed.

I was wondering if there is a way to return the position of a cell relative to another. For example, I have named a cell Current_Scenerio_Start, if I could get the position of this cell relative to Current_Scenerio_Start (say its 5 rows down and 3 columns across), I could then paste the value in the when the cell font is green into my new range relative to another starting position.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that/if it's even possible.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteThesisA()

Dim CurrentScenrioRange As Range
Dim ThesisARange As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set CurrentScenrioRange = Scenerios.Range("Current_Scenerio:Current_Scenerio_End")
Set ThesisARange = Scenerios.Range("Thesis_A:Thesis_A_End")


For Each Cell In CurrentScenrioRange
    Cell.Select
    If Cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
        With Scenerios
            .Range(ThesisARange).Value = .Range(CurrentScenrioRange).Value
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Right now I'm just getting errors as I know that I'm not the range I want to paste into correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not currently able to test either of these suggestions. They seemed like they would work (in my head), but maybe I've missed something.

If both ranges are rectangular/square (i.e. each row has same number of columns and each column has same number of rows), then maybe swap the `For Each` loop for two `For` loops (one for rows, one for columns). Something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteThesisA()

    Dim CurrentScenrioRange As Range
    Dim ThesisARange As Range

    Dim greenFontColour As Long
    greenFontColour = RGB(0, 176, 80)

    Set CurrentScenrioRange = Scenerios.Range("Current_Scenerio:Current_Scenerio_End")
    Set ThesisARange = Scenerios.Range("Thesis_A:Thesis_A_End")

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = 1 To CurrentScenrioRange.Rows.Count
        Dim columnIndex As Long
        For columnIndex = 1 To CurrentScenrioRange.Columns.Count
            If CurrentScenrioRange(rowIndex, columnIndex).Font.Color = greenFontColour Then
                ThesisARange(rowIndex, columnIndex).Value = CurrentScenrioRange(rowIndex, columnIndex).Value
            End If
        Next columnIndex
    Next rowIndex
End Sub
```

Otherwise (if they're not rectangular/square), maybe you could try to calculate the relative row and column indexes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteThesisA()

    Dim CurrentScenrioRange As Range
    Dim ThesisARange As Range

    Set CurrentScenrioRange = Scenerios.Range("Current_Scenerio:Current_Scenerio_End")
    Set ThesisARange = Scenerios.Range("Thesis_A:Thesis_A_End")

    Dim greenFontColour As Long
    greenFontColour = RGB(0, 176, 80)

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In CurrentScenrioRange

        Dim relativeRowIndex As Long
        relativeRowIndex = Cell.Row - CurrentScenrioRange.Rows(1).Row + 1 ' Might be better to second figure in a variable, instead of re-reading.

        Dim relativeColumnIndex As Long
        relativeColumnIndex = Cell.Column - CurrentScenrioRange.Columns(1).Column + 1 ' Might be better to second figure in a variable, instead of re-reading.

        If Cell.Font.Color = greenFontColour Then
            ThesisARange(relativeRowIndex, relativeColumnIndex).Value = Cell.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! The source isn't a square so the second code worked. It's quite slow to update, I'm assuming that's because it is searching through each cell individually?

Comment: @bigalbunyan, yes, I imagine it's slow because reading/writing cells individually is a slow process. You can, to some degree, speed things up by toggling `Application.ScreenUpdating`, `Application.Calculation` before and after the loop. If you provide more details about the shape/location of the ranges (and what's causing certain cells to have a green font), it might be easier to say how things can be sped up.

Comment: Sorry, I actually misread your solution. The location of the ranges are both rectangular so either solution actually worked. The reason that the cells are green is the workbook is colour coded to make review easier. Green values, for instance, indicate a reference from another worksheet. Black values are calculations, and blue values are inputs.